# Crystal Report prompts for Login when using Sub-Reports through VS 2013

Tags: vb.net, authentication, crystal-reports, subreport

Microsoft SQL Database
VB.NET in Visual Studio 2013

I am currently using a form for launching the crystal reports and it works perfectly fine for reports that has no sub-reports. The code I have used to build it is an adaptation from https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1676673.

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine


Public Class Crystal
    Public RPTSRC As String
    Public RPTNAME As String


    Private Sub configureCRYSTALREPORT()
        Dim myConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME"
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "CR"
        myConnectionInfo.Password = "1234"
        setDBLOGONforREPORT(myConnectionInfo)
    End Sub


    Private Sub setDBLOGONforREPORT(ByVal myconnectioninfo As ConnectionInfo)
        Dim mytableloginfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
        mytableloginfos = CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo
        For Each myTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo In mytableloginfos
            myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = myconnectioninfo
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub MGM_PT_MNT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) - 10, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) - 35)
        Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2)
        Me.Text = RPTNAME
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPTSRC
        configureCRYSTALREPORT()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As per my understanding, this only manages to pass the values only to the main report and hence the sub report requests for the credentials.Unfortunately, the KPI report I have developed requires 2 subreports to be a part of the main report and the Management cannot be expected to type the username and password to view this. Furthermore, we are using SQL Authentication only.

Can someone please help me to pass the login details to the SubReports for VB.NET? Any help appreciated .

EDIT:

Thanks to Jonathan, I got the answer to my question and would like to make it easier for others too who are also in search of a similar requirement.

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class Crystal
    'This is only needed if you would like another form to send the Report Name (RPTNAME) and the Location (RPTSRC). Location can be a Shared UNC Path.
    Public RPTSRC As String
    Public RPTNAME As String


    Private Sub configureCRYSTALREPORT(report As ReportDocument)
        Dim myConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME"
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "Username"
        myConnectionInfo.Password = "Password"
        setDBLOGONforREPORT(myConnectionInfo)
        configureSubREPORT(report, myConnectionInfo)

    End Sub

    Private Sub setDBLOGONforREPORT(ByVal myconnectioninfo As ConnectionInfo)
        Dim mytableloginfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
        mytableloginfos = CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo
        For Each myTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo In mytableloginfos
            myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = myconnectioninfo
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub configureSubREPORT(report As ReportDocument, info As ConnectionInfo)
        Dim rD As ReportDocument
        Dim table As Table

        For Each rD In report.Subreports
            For Each table In rD.Database.Tables
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = info
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub MGM_PT_MNT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) - 8, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) - 44)
        Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2)
        Me.Text = RPTNAME
        Dim report = New ReportDocument
        report.Load(RPTSRC)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        configureCRYSTALREPORT(report)
        'EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = "false"
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very long time since I used VB, so please forgive if the syntax is not right, but I do have CR Sub-Reports in c#.

What you need to do, is pass the logoninfo down to all the sub-reports.  Something like this:

Change your load sub:

Instead of:

```
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPTSRC 
    configureCRYSTALREPORT()
```

Do

```
    Dim report = New ReportDocument
    report.Load(RPTSRC)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report 
    configureCRYSTALREPORT(report)
```

Then make sub routine

```
Private Sub configureSubREPORT(report as ReportDocument, info as ConnectionInfo)
    Dim rD As ReportDocument
    Dim table As Table

    For Each rD In report.Subreports
        For Each table In rD.Database.Tables
            table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = info
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Finally change existing sub as follows:

```
Private Sub configureCRYSTALREPORT(report AS ReportDocument)
    Dim myConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME"
    myConnectionInfo.UserID = "CR"
    myConnectionInfo.Password = "1234"
    setDBLOGONforREPORT(myConnectionInfo)
    configureSubREPORT(report, myConnectionInfo)

End Sub
```

That should do it.  But as I said before I am very rusty on VB!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan for your help. However, I am afraid, I might have to trouble you further as my coding skills is still novice.

Do I add the lines you posted after the main report login in the section

`Private Sub setDBLOGONforREPORT(ByVal myconnectioninfo As ConnectionInfo)`

Also, I get the report location and name from different forms, so how do I go about with the ReportClass? Sorry for my extremely limited knowledge.

Comment: @FareedAbdulHameed See my answer (I have just edited it)

Comment: Your VB.NET Coding skills are perfect and you have helped me solve this irritating issue. I cant thank you enough. I will update my first post and keep it generic and maybe add it as part of documentation here so that it would be useful for someone who has been in the same spot as me. Thanks again Jonathan, couldn't have done it without your help. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Also good to keep questions as generic as possible - you do help more people that way.